# C# method naming best practices

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

I have a coworker that keeps renaming object and method in my code. Add S, removing S etc..

I would like to know what is the best way in your opinion.

Suppose I have a class Client.

This Client can set two reminders (wakeupReminder and leaveReminder).

Each of these reminders have different settings.

So I created a Class called **WakeUpReminderSettings**. He told me that I should rename it to **WakeUpReminderSetting** because it is not a collection.

I also created a method that return all reminders settings. I named it **GetClientRemindersSettings**.

Again, he renamed it to **GetClientReminderSettings**. He's argument: Only the last word should be pluralized..

I would like to have your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're right in both cases. A WeakUpReminderSettings can be an aggregate of different settings without being a collection, and if your method return settings for multiple reminders, it makes sense to pluralize reminder even if it's not the last work.
Then again, naming conventions are really something subjective, if your coworker is not above you in the hierarchy, I'd tell him to stop messing with your work for minor changes like this.